# Delete records based on specific values ​in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table like this:

| event | value |
| --- | --- |
| seed | 57 |
| ghy | 869 |
| repo | 5324 |
| repo | null |
| repo | null |
| trans | 32 |
| harv | 12 |
| weig | 6995 |
| repo | 45 |
| repo | null |

I would like to delete all records where event = 'repo', but after event = 'harv'.

I mean the expected result:

| event | value |
| --- | --- |
| seed | 57 |
| ghy | 869 |
| repo | 5324 |
| repo | null |
| repo | null |
| trans | 32 |
| harv | 12 |
| weig | 6995 |

Do you know how to do it the easiest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html) for match all next rows after matching `harv` and chain by `&` for bitwise `AND` or `|` for bitwise `OR` with mask for compare for equal or not equal `repo`:

```
df = df[~(df['event'].eq('harv').cummax() & df['event'].eq('repo'))]
#alternative
#df = df[~df['event'].eq('harv').cummax() | df['event'].ne('repo')]
print (df)
   event   value
0   seed    57.0
1    ghy   869.0
2   repo  5324.0
3   repo     NaN
4   repo     NaN
5  trans    32.0
6   harv    12.0
7   weig  6995.0
```